# Is the word 'primitive' attributive or predicative?

Tags: grammar

I've known the word 'primitive' is an attributive adjective. But in a sentence from the school test, it is used as a predicative adjective. The sentence is the following: Forests in Vietnam are still primitive. I'd like to know whether the sentence is correct.

Comment: _Predicative_ and _attributive_ are descriptions of the adjective's position in the sentence; they are not attributes of the adjective itself. Any adjective can be predicative or attributive, depending on how it is used in a sentence. In the sentence "The primitive forest is in Vietnam," _primitive_ is _attributive._ In your sentence, it is _predicative:_ it is part of the _predicate._ The sentence is fine.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Mostly right, but there are some adjectives which are used only attributively (examples: *former*, *mere*, *only*) or predicatively (examples: *awake*, *alive*, and other *a-* forms representing former preposition phrases).

Comment: It is said in OALD that the word 'primitive' is usually used attributively. Now in this sentence, it is used predicatively. I'd like to know whether it is natural or not.

Comment: @theinlwin _Usually_ doesn't mean that it should not be used in the predicate, only that it's uncommon. The sentence is not ungrammatical. OED provides examples of predicative use, e.g. _The group of motions in the euclidean plane is primitive._ They are mostly  in descriptions of maths, but there's nothing to prohibit the usage you present.

Comment: @StoneyB I typoed "any" for "an," but only noticed it now. There's a long list of attr. onlies: mere, sheer, etc., and pred. onlies: besides the a- list, there's fond, and a couple of others that escape me atm. Until I started looking just now, I'd forgotten all about the traditionalist proscription against the predicative _little._ Is that properly in the dustbin, do you think?

Comment: @P.E.Dant - I've never paid any attention to it, on Shakespeare's authority: *Though she be but little, she is fierce.*

Comment: @StoneyB An utter non sequitur, but your take on [this](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/105336/37009) is humbly solicited.